# How to change range value to cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function :

`=COUNTIF(Data!$V$6:$V$1029;Analyse_ALL!C7)`

At the moment i need to type "1029" (the last row with cell value in the column) manually.
I made a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) function that counts the last row, and i made it write that result into a cell.

How do i take my vba result/cell value into my function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: replace $V$1029 with the address of the cell where your function is used, or simply call your function instead ( if its a function, cause it sounds like youve wrote a sub )

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have the VBA write the complete formula for you in stead of just the 1029:

   `Range("**Coordinates of the formula**").Formula = "=COUNTIF(Data!$V$6:$V$"& **originalVBAresult** & ";Analyse_ALL!C7)"`
2. You can have an OFFSET within the COUNTIF which links to the cell you write the 1029 to:

   `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(Data!$V$6;0;0;**Cell with 1029 in it**);Analyse_ALL!C7)`

Comment: Hey, first i tries the OFFSET method but that doesn't seem to work, i get default error message. How does he know the range is still in column V

Comment: Offset should work perfectly fine as long as you actually fill the formula in and not just use my line directly... What is the default error message you get?

Comment: offcource i changed this: **Cell with 1029 in it** but in what do i change the 0 values?

Comment: you dont change the 0 into anything, the first one is for the rows you MOVE the V6 with (which you dont want to move, hence 0) then second is the same for the columns (which you also dont want to move, hence 0)

Comment: what is the address of the cell where you vba code dumps the number?

Comment: or what is the name of your VBA function? Then you can change the formula to: `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(Data!$V$6;0;0;NAME_OF_YOUR_FUNCTION);Analyse_ALL!C7)`

Comment: Hey, it works now, i probably types something wrong the first time. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome, please mark the question as answered by clicking the mark to the left of the answer. Others will know your problem is resolved and doesnt need further answering.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to

1. Detect the last used row in column V in Sheet `Data`
2. If that row exceeds 6, then add this formula to `A1`, `=COUNTIF(Data!$V$6:$VX;Analyse_ALL!C7)` (where `X` is the last row from step 1)

**code**

```
Sub InsertFormula()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp)
If rng1.Row > 6 Then
[a1].FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(Data!R6C22:R" & rng1.Row & "C22,Analyse_ALL!R7C3)"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the last argument `R[-7]C[-6]` requires further revision before implementation...

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I understand what you are trying to do but i don't understand the R6C22, C22, -7 - 6

Comment: its the offset Row 6 C 22 -7 to left and -6 up

Comment: @user2156096 `R6C22` is cell `V6`, `R" & rng1.Row & "C22` will return the last used cell in column V etc